# Procedural Cracked Hole Material

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, procedural

I want a way to generate procedural cracks like in the pictures below:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/wEl2nFj]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I’ve been trying to do it with Voronoi textures, but have so far been unsuccessful:

[image]

Does anyone have ideas for how to do this?

Comment: A few pointers : It's hard to decipher your node group, maybe try to post a higher res screenshot, use a 2D texture instead of 3D to get rid of the thick bands, use a gradient texture instead of a color ramp to get a smoother gradient, use a noise texture to vary slitghtly the input coordinates

Comment: I've fixed the image, and used a 2D texture, but I'm confused about what you mean by the gradient texture?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is the best *I* could do:

[image]

[image]

Feel free to mess around with the sliders. You can customize the hole in the middle, and the cracks' thickness and size.

[image]

Comment: Thank You! This is perfect

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Just letting you know, your last image is apparently linked from another site rather than embedded, unfortunately a site that my ISP doesn't agree with, so it's coming up as broken.

Comment: Interesting, since I just drag and dropped the images onto the page, so it should be embedded. I'll edit the answer and try again, see if it works.